Find shadowed vertices in 2d curve with point light
I have a set of vertices that form a curve in x and y. The curve is smooth, not convex, doesn't intersect and there are no vertical or beyond vertical parts. The x values are unique integers. The picture below illustrates an exemplary curve. You can also see the point light source above the curve. This light is always well above the curve.

Now I want to calculate which of the vertices are shadowed by the mesh. If possible I want to avoid casting rays and calculating where they possibly intersect with the mesh. Since the mesh is a simple line I'm guessing there is an easier way to find the shadowed vertices.
What I tried is calculating the angle between the y-axis and the ray from the light to each vertex with angle = arctan((y_point - y[i]), (x_point - x[i])). This represents the angle between a ray to the left of the light source to each vertex. I Have drawn the rays in the image below. As you can see, the points at x==[3,5,21,22,23] should be shadowed, that's why I have manually coloured them green.

Now if the curve was flat, for each point of increasing x the angle calculated above should also be increasing. If it however decreases compared to the previous point, either this point or the previous point are in shadow. The results from this are shown below:

As you can see it correctly detects vertices at x==[21,22], but it misses x==23 and it only detects the neighbours of the shadowed vertices on the left.
For x==23 I thought I could calculate the cummax(angle) for each point and compare the point's angle to this cummax angle. If angle < cummax(angle) then that point is shadowed. This now also catches the vertex at x==23, but still fails on the left side.
How can I fix the left side?
I'm working with python but this should apply to any language. If possible I want to avoid casting rays and calculating every edge where the ray could intersect the curve. If you want to replicate the curve the coordinates are
"x": [ 1, 2,  3, 4, 5,6,7,8,13,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,]
"y": [-2,-3,-10,-1,-2,2,3,4, 7, 5, 5, 5, 3, 1, 1, 1,]
"point": (11, 16)


Following your own idea, you just need to check the left and right sides of the light separately:
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = np.array([ 1, 2,  3, 4, 5,6,7,8,13,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,])
y = np.array([-2,-3,-10,-1,-2,2,3,4, 7, 5, 5, 5, 3, 1, 1, 1,])
point = (11, 16)

xp, yp = point
n = len(x)
# find the "index" of the light point: xp will be between x[ip-1] and x[ip]
for ip in range(n):
    if x[ip] >= xp:
        break

# following r3mainer's comment, using simple gradients
# grads = (yp-y)/(xp-x) instead of more expensive angle = arctan(grads)
# will work just the same...
angles = np.arctan2(yp-y, xp-x)
cummax = np.maximum.accumulate
cummin = np.minimum.accumulate
shadow_R = angles[ip:] < cummax(angles[ip:])
shadow_L = (angles[ip:None:-1] > cummin(angles[ip:None:-1]))[::-1]
shadow = np.hstack((shadow_L, shadow_R))


plt.figure(1).clf()
plt.plot(x, y, 'o-b')
plt.plot(*point, 'o')
for xi,yi,s in zip(x,y,shadow):
    s = 'r:' if s else 'g'
    plt.plot([xi,xp], [yi,yp], s)



I can't see any need for calculating arctangents; surely a simple calculation of the gradient (∆y/∆x) would be sufficient to figure out if the angle is increasing or decreasing? That ought to make the algorithm considerably faster.

Oh right, you can just "divide" the curve based on the position of the light. That is an oversight I made while trying to explain my problem in a more visual way. In reality I don't know the point or the angles, I just know a value for each point that is mostly increasing with x, just like the angles. Do you also know a solution that - once you have calculated the angles - doesn't take the light position into account?

That seems very correct to me @r3mainer, was just building on OP's idea and fixing their bug. Didn't look for any further optimization, but your suggestion seems like an obvious easy one indeed...

Your light has to be between the indices where the angles cross over the 90 degree value. (or if you use gradients like @r3mainer suggestion, where they switch from positive to negative)... That said I'm not sure how you'd compute the gradients without knowing your points and light to start with... next time make sure you create an actual [mre]... or you'll keep getting answers to different problems :)
